# how to pass a parameter to ajaxed loop script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This function get a parameter and pass it to this this

```
$.arte({'ajax_url':'getRealTimeUpdates.php?activity_id='+id, 'on_success':updateLiveUpdates}).start();
```

> [where this line of code feches the upadtes from server each a
>   specific time period as a jaxed loop]

when I call the function `showLiveUpdates(id)` with some parameter for example `id=5`, this line remember id=5 for all this function calls even different parameters ! 
I want each time I call the function with different `id` this line of code get the new `id`

{{ where arte is JQuery plug-in : Ajax Real Time Extension, this is its website [click here](http://code.google.com/p/arte/)}}

js code :

```
function showLiveUpdates(id)
{
    //$.arte().stop();

    $("#liveUpdates").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#liveUpdates").html("");
    $("#liveUpdates").append("<div><textarea rows='2' cols='49' id='txtLiveUpdates'></textarea></div>");
    $("#liveUpdates").append("<div><input type='button' id='btnliveUpdatesShare' value='share' onClick='addComment("+id+","+getCookie("userId")+")'></div>");
    last="";
    $.arte({'ajax_url':'getRealTimeUpdates.php?activity_id='+id, 'on_success':updateLiveUpdates}).start();

}
```

I call it like this:

```
<input type='button' onClick='showLiveUpdates(<? echo $_GET["id"];?>)' />
```

### edit

```
function updateLiveUpdates(data)
{
    if(data!=last)
    {
        $("#liveUpdates").append("<div id='updates"+ii+"' style='display:none' >"+data+"</div>");
        $("#updates"+ii).fadeIn();
        last=data;
    }
    ii++;
}
```

getRealTimeUpdates.php

```
<?php  

require("database.php");
$activity_id=$_GET["activity_id"];
$query = "SELECT id,comment from comments where activity_id=$activity_id order by id desc limit 0,1";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row["id"]."-".$row["comment"];

?>
```

Comment: Are checking that getRealTimeUpdates.php is return something different?

Comment: yes, but I need to send a parameter to getRealTimeUpdates.php

Comment: Are you sure that `id` in the function is different each time?

Comment: I die a little inside when I see jQuery written along-side obtrusive event bindings.

Comment: @Adam Terlson sorry, I don't understand "jQuery written along-side obtrusive event bindings" .. what is the problem and possible solution ?

Comment: The problem is anything written as such: `onClick='foo()'` in your HTML.  Solution: unobtrusive binding with jQuery: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript  Such as: `$('#foo').click(function() { });`

Comment: how to pass id as parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Creating a function scope for the `id` variable:

```
function createData(id) {
    return function () {
        return {
            'ajax_url':'getRealTimeUpdates.php?activity_id='+id,
            'on_success':updateLiveUpdates
        }
    }
}

for (var id = 0; id < 5; i++) {
    $.arte(createData(id)()).start();
}
```

**EDIT 1** Just looked at the code at http://code.google.com/p/arte/source/browse/trunk/jquery-plugin-arte.js.

There is a shared `_config` property that gets overwritten, and the URL used is always `_config['ajax_url']`.

**EDIT 2** I've posted [a demo of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/YMtxj/3/) to demonstrate your issue. So it looks like you cannot call this function multiple times, because the internal state is shared.

**EDIT 3** I've updated a jsfiddle with a rough attempt at making this code work as you desire. [The demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/X85FH/10/). The new code keeps no state and (seems to) successfully run 5 update loops before terminating them after 3 seconds.

Comment: The same thing , I think the problem is in this function  '$.arte().start();' .. it remembers value ..

Comment: How about edited answer? Added inner function and immediate call of that function from the loop.

Comment: function createData(id) {
    return function () {
  alert(id);
        return {
            'ajax_url':'getRealTimeUpdates.php?activity_id='+id,
            'on_success':updateLiveUpdates
        }
    }
} alert work fine sends a new id each time ,, but the function retuen the same id !!!

Comment: Where's `ii` coming from? That's going to retain the last value isn't it? You'll probably be better off passing `ii` and a flag indicating `last` in the `data` object.

Comment: Think you're right - look at the code - http://code.google.com/p/arte/source/browse/trunk/jquery-plugin-arte.js - there is a shared `_config` element. So when you call `arte` this will get overwritten.

Comment: sorry I am not expert , can you explain more ? :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to agree with your conclusion that the library does not support your requirements. I've also added a simple demo to show how the URL is not unique with each call, but is remembered.

Comment: so I can't use url re-writing ! . do you think using cookie is a good alternative to share id value ?

Comment: You will either have to not use arte, or fix it for your purposes to *not* use a shared config object.

Comment: again I say I am still a beginner in jquery and javascript . is there a problem in cookies ? , BTW thanks for your help, I have accpeted your answer

Comment: Check out new edit. I've hacked the arte plugin, but use at your own risk. It seems to work though!! When you try the demo, make sure you have Firebug Net panel open to see the requests being fired.